# Finder "Always open with" ignored

Tags: finder

On my Macbook Air (El Capitan) -

Why is it that when I select `Open With>Other...`

Enable `all applications`

check the checkbox `Always open with`

[image]

It still makes me do it all over again,... every time!!!

I am trying to open xml files with Chrome.  But every time I select one from Finder and do open with...

If I just choose `Open` then XCode opens it.

What does the `Always open with` checkbox actually do? Is it for decoration only, and has no function?  It doesn't do what I think it should.  Please advise.

Comment: This happens when you SELECT "Chrome" from the all applications and THEN tick the 'Always open with" checkbox?

Comment: @bjbk Yes and the order of events does not seem to matter either - whether I choose the app first and then check the box or the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is making Finder always open this *specific* *file* with Chrome.

What you want is to open *all* XML files with Chrome. To do this:

1. Right click the XML file.
2. Choose Get Info
3. Under "Open with", select Chrome and then click "Change All..."

Comment: Thank you! This is far from obvious in the "user friendly" Finder.

Comment: Even the specific file won't open with whatever you select in Mojave. The checkbox seems to do nothing but fill up an otherwise empty space.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to open all xml files in Chrome, you need to click the `Change All...` button in the `File | Get info` (cmd+i) window.

Comment: What does `Always open with` in the file open dialog mean then?  What's its usage?

Comment: That only applies to that single file, not all files based on the file extension. Personally I never found this feature useful, since if I want to open a png file with GIMP for example, than I want to open all png files with gimp. Otherwise it is hard to expect what application will open when I double click on a file.